# Cannot log in to linuxmint at all

Tags: linux, login, linux-mint

I have a dual boot system running Windows7 and Mint 13. Somehow, long story (I tried to uninstall my LAMP server in one go) I managed to delete my login managers. I tried to boot in text mode and install one but I didn't get a login prompt. Next I tried recovery mode, but when I try to enable networking the system hangs indefinitely while mounting the file system. Next round, live USB disk (getting CD's is a hassle at the moment.) Any other ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by login manager? Which package did you remove?

Comment: I had KDE and MATE installed. I accidentally removed all of KDE including KDM. I think it must have gotten rid of gdm3 as well

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a bash prompt you should be able to add the following to the end of the line which says "kernel"

```
init=/bin/bash
```

This will bypass all the login scripts and give you a bash prompt (as root).   With some luck you can then fix your disk problems, then reboot in text mode, then install your Window Manager from the command line.

Another possibility (if you are lucky) might be to boot the system and see if you can switch to a text console (try  X) where X is each number between 1 and 7.  With some luck you should be asked for a login on at least one of these terminals, and then install the manager.

Comment: I tried and cannot get a text console (mentioned in my question). Whne you say "You should be able to get a a bash prompt" do you mean root without networking in recovery mode, because that's the only prompt i can get?

Comment: And which file do I add that line to?

Comment: You don't add it to a file, you edit the bootloader when your computer starts up. The whole idea is to get your computer into a state where you can start repairs.

Comment: No, recovery mode is probably something different.  Booting with init=/bin/bash does not set up any network environment or run any scripts.  It starts the most basic system (ie the kernel) and replaces the init script (which loads all the services and the environment) with a simple bash shell - not services are loaded.